# Google Docs API Creating Documents on Python Service is Not Defined

Tags: python, google-docs

I am trying to create a document on Google Docs API using python, but when I use the script I get this error - `NameError: name 'service' is not defined`.

This is the script I am using (from https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python):

```
title = 'My Document'
body = {
    'title': title
}
doc = service.documents() \
    .create(body=body).execute()
print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(
    doc.get('title')))
```

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should provide a [mre] so we can see why you're expecting `service` to be defined at that point. Otherwise I don't see how we can possibly help you. The only possible answer with what you've given us is that you never defined `service`, but obviously that's what the error is telling you anyway.

Comment: Hi Random Davis, my confusion stems from Google Docs providing the above as an example of how to create a document, but it doesn't work. Here is the link - https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

I posted this as a comment but I might as well have it be an answer, since I found the issue.

The issue is that you can't just run that code alone and expect anything to work. From looking around the API documentation you copied that code from ([here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python)), it's clear that you didn't start with the [Python Quickstart page](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python), which has an example script that sets up the `service` variable among other things. Once you use that code to define and set up `service`, the code from your example should work as expected.

Here's an example of what I meant - just took the example, pasted it here, and pasted in the code that you were trying to run below the comment `# Create a document called 'My Document'`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly']

# The ID of a sample document.
DOCUMENT_ID = '195j9eDD3ccgjQRttHhJPymLJUCOUjs-jmwTrekvdjFE'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Create a document called 'My Document'
    title = 'My Document'
    body = { 'title': title }
    doc = service.documents().create(body=body).execute()
    print('Created document with title: {0}'.format(doc.get('title')))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So I have now run the code with the Python Quickstart page script, but it still says service is not defined (even though it looks like it is)?

Comment: You have to actually run your code in the same [scope](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) that `service` was defined in. In the example, it's defined in `main()`, so if you're trying to access it outside of `main`, that's outside of its scope, so it will be undefined still. You could also just pass `service` to the function that requires it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you provide an example in the Google Docs API context?

Comment: @rafholder okay I put in an example, it's below the comment `# Create a document called 'My Document'`. That's what I meant by putting it in scope. You could also put that code inside a function, and pass `service` to that function.

Comment: Thanks Random Davis!